# Fourier transform of vanishing function in $L^2$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $u$ be a function in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$,

Question1:

Is $\left \|  u \right \|_{L^{2}} =0 $ implies  that $F\left(u\right)=0$?

Question2:

Is $\left \|  u \right \|_{L^{2}}   > 0$  implies that there exists a positive constant $c> 0$ such that $F\left ( u \right )> c$?

Note that $F(u)$ is the Fourier transform of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for question 1 is yes, because the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}:L^2\to L^2$ is an isomorphism between Hilbert spaces. In particular for linearity it maps 0 to 0 (actually you only need $\mathcal{F}$ to be a linear mapping, which is easy to verify).

Remark that the $0$ of $L^2$ is a class of equivalence modulo a.e. equality, so you would have $\mathcal{F}(u)=0$ a.e.

The second part is false. To see it, take any $u\in L^2, u\ne0$ (and hence with strictly positive norm) and consider $\mathcal{F}(u)$. If there is a constant $C$ for which $\mathcal{F}(u)>C$, then $\mathcal{F}(-u)=-\mathcal{F}(u)<-C<0$ and $-u$ and $u$ have the same norm.

Comment: In question2, I take the implication $/F\left ( u \right )/$>$ c$.

Comment: @user326064 Still false. Remark that $\mathcal{F}(u')(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\mathcal{F}(u)(\xi)$ and apply this rule to the Gaussian $u(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$, which is a fixed point for $\mathcal{F}$. You have that $\Vert u\Vert_2>0$ and $\mathcal{F}(u)(0)=0$.

Comment: Using the Plancherel's theorem in $L^2$ , what is the condition on $/F(u)/$ such that assures that $\left \| u \right \|_{L^{2}} > c$?

Comment: Plancherel states that $\mathcal{F}:L^2\to L^2$ is a linear isometry, i.e. $\Vert\mathcal{F}(u)\Vert_2=\Vert u\Vert_2$, hence you only need to require that $$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\mathcal{F}(u)(\xi)|^2d\xi\right)^{1/2}>c$$

Comment: Is it possible to write this condition with only $/F(u)/$ ? This is my question.

Answer (score 0):

If $u \neq 0$   on a subest of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ then $F(u) \neq 0$ and thus $/F(u)/ \neq 0$
Therefore, $\left \|  u \right \|_{L^{2}}  $ = $\left \|  F(u) \right \|_{L^{2}}  $$\neq 0$.
the inverse  is true.